# Filter same data in table Mysql

Tags: mysql

My table structure is something like this

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║     ID ║ OUTLET   ║ LAT      ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║      1 ║ OUTLET1  ║ 19.0000  ║
║      2 ║ OUTLET2  ║ 19.0000  ║
║      3 ║ OUTLET3  ║ 19.5236  ║
║      4 ║ OUTLET4  ║ 19.4756  ║   
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

I am expecting output something like this

```
╔═════════════════╦══════════╗
║ OUTLET          ║ LAT      ║
╠═════════════════╬══════════╣
║ OUTLET1, OUTLET2║ 19.0000  ║
║ OUTLET3         ║ 19.5236  ║
║ OUTLET4         ║ 19.4756  ║   
╚═════════════════╩══════════╝
```

Is there any way I can get this output. I don't know how to filter out rows in same table. Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` and `group by`

```
select 
group_concat(OUTLET) as OUTLET,
`LAT`
from table_name
group by `LAT`
```